# Index and search files attached inside pdf

Tags: search, pdf

I'am going to migrate a lot of documents from Lotus Notes to Sharepoint O365. The export format will be a pdf with files (Word, Excel, Pdf) as attachments inside the pdf. 
Will these attached files be indexed by the search engine in O365? I know that the main pdf is no problem to index.

Regards,
Jonas

Comment: Do the PDFs contain the same info as the embedded Office doc?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and while it does index the PDF content it does not index the attached content in a Word document.